# JavaScript to animated image

Tags: javascript

is it possible to convert JavaScript animation code to a .gif animation?

I'd like to convert this code : http://jsbin.com/ugifab/199/edit .

Thanks

Comment: You might be interested in [Jsgif](https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif)

Comment: You can't reference scripts from raw GitHub.  Use http://padolsey.net/p/Sonic/repo/src/sonic.js

Comment: You can also use [rawgithub.com](http://rawgithub.com). Your code with the modified URI: http://jsbin.com/ugifab/201/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not talking about `<canvas>` image manipulation, you cannot create screenshots or screen videos from the document using JavaScript. Therefore, only using JavaScript on the client-side is not sufficient.

If you are using a `<canvas>`, this is technically possible. You could use [jsgif](https://github.com/antimatter15/jsgif) as brbcoding mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you did want to do the canvas approach it would look something like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLK7v/3/

hope this helps out

```
var google = true;
function runFunction(){
    var can = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext('2d');
    if(google){
        google = false;
        can.fillStyle="#000000";
        can.fillRect(0,0,100,100); //clear screen
        can.drawImage(Itwo,0,0); //draw image

    }
    else{
        google = true;
        can.fillStyle="#000000";
        can.fillRect(0,0,100,100); //clear screen
        can.drawImage(Ione,0,0);   //draw next image
  }
}

var t=setInterval(runFunction,1000);
```